# How to start an immediate transaction of Sqlite in Qt?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

Got troubles with using QSqlDatabase::transaction().
I want to start a transaction of Sqlite in Qt and I know this function : bool QSqlDatabase::transaction():

```
if(db.transaction())
{
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    // do stuff

   if(!db.commit())
   {
        qDebug() << "Failed to commit";
        db.rollback();
   }
}
```

My problem is that I want to start an immediate transaction as follows:

```
> begin immediate;
> ...(operation)
> commit;
```

This function bool QSqlDatabase::transaction() will start a default transaction.
There will be several users using this program to access sqlite database so I need to control their access orders. If one user is writing, others can't read or write. It seems that I need to start an immediate transaction.

So how to start an immediate transaction by QSqlDatabase::transaction() ?
Is there way to specify transaction type in QSqlDatabase::transaction() ?

I use this to start an immediate transaction:

```
QsqlQuery query(myDatabase);
query.exec("begin immediate;");
query.exec(...) // read or write database.
query.exec("commit;");
```

It didn't work. There is still wrong data caused by multiple user access in database.

Comment: You need to use WAL mode - one writer / multiple readers

Comment: SQLite was not designed for multiple concurrent writers, immediate mode does not change this. You need to make sure your writes are serialized or synchronized, i.e. by using a mutex.